# Replacement Issues with dash check (range out of order)

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have two strings I'm trying to match but keep getting out of bounds errors or unmatch issues.

This is coded in LUA btw.

`RegExp1 =  "%[%d+%. Trade.-%]"`

With string example:
`"[5. Trade - City] [SomeCharacterName]: Testing Chat"`

Should be returned as:
`"[5. TR] [SomeCharacterName]: Testing Chat"`

RegExp2 =  "%[%d+%. Trade (Services).-%]"

With string example:
`"[5. Trade (Services) - City] [SomeCharacterName]: Testing Chat"`

Should be returned as:
`"[5. TRS] [SomeCharacterName]: Testing Chat"`

but both RegExp1 and RegExp2 give out of bounds errors and RegExp2 never matches (Services) portion of the string no matter how many variations and escapes I tend to do.

In general I would like to ignore everything after the "-" dash in the regexp and always replace the text at the front of it with something else.

Examples:

```
[2. Channel - SomeCity]  to [2. CHN]
[2. Channel (Services) - SomeCity]  to [2. CHS]
[2. Channel] to [2. CH]   <--this one is missing the city name
[4. SomeDefense] to [4. SD]
```

etc.. etc..

Thanks for the help!!!

https://regex101.com/r/sn6axG/1

Comment: Try: `/\[\d+. Trade.-.*/g`.

Comment: Are you coding in Lua? `%d` is a Lua pattern to match a digit.

Comment: Yes it's coded in LUA.  The above regExp seemed to replace the entire line with TR instead of the text in the brackets.

Comment: Try `"(%[%d+%. )Trade.-%]"` as the pattern and replace with `"%1TR]"`, see https://ideone.com/5ZTUnE. Note that Lua patterns are not regular expressions.

Comment: Ah yes it's pattern matching not regexp.  Sorry about that @WiktorStribiżew I occasionally forget the difference. Hmm seems to work but still seems to overwrite (Services) since the word Trade is in it.

`[1. Trade (Services) -City] should be [TRS]`
`[1. Trade - City] should be [TR]`

Comment: Because you need a different pattern for the second string, see https://ideone.com/VUJ8DL

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah okay I see now.  You are checking for text in () in the second one and removing it if found.  Thanks this helps a lot!  I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Lua patterns are not regular expressions and can't be tested at regex101.com. `.-` in Lua patterns is the `(?s).*?` regex pattern equivalent, and when you used `[.-%]`, you defined an invalid ASCII char range.

In your first case, you can use `"(%[%d+%. )Trade.-%]"` as the pattern and `"%1TR]` as the replacement pattern.

In the second case, you can use `"(%[%d+%. )Trade %([^()]*%).-%]"` pattern and `"%1TRS]"` replacement.

See the [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/VUJ8DL):

```lua
local s = "[5. Trade - City] [SomeCharacterName]: Testing Chat"
local result, _ = s:gsub("(%[%d+%. )Trade.-%]", "%1TR]")
print( result )
-- [5. TR] [SomeCharacterName]: Testing Chat

local text = "[5. Trade (Services) - City] [SomeCharacterName]: Testing Chat"
local res, _ = text:gsub("(%[%d+%. )Trade %([^()]*%).-%]", "%1TRS]")
print( res )
-- [5. TRS] [SomeCharacterName]: Testing Chat
```